# Knockout k.apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to hide a div with a particular animation using Knockout, and it works but I'm getting this error:

> knockout-3.4.2.js:90 Uncaught TypeError: k.apply is not a function
>       at HTMLDivElement.

This is the HTML I'm using:

```
<div id="wikipedia-text" data-bind="click: hideWikipedia($element)"></div>
```

And the function I'm calling:

```
hideWikipedia = async function(wikiText) {
    wikiText.style.animationName = "goUp";
    await sleep(1000); // The animation lasts 1s, this avoids to hide the div while the animation is going
    wikiText.style.display = "none";
};
```

Can someone help me to understand what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you pass to the `click` binding is evaluated upon calling `applyBindings`. Therefore, `hideWikipedia` is called immediately resulting in the element being hidden 1000ms after calling `ko.applyBindings`.

`click` expects to receive a *function*, which means `hideWikipedia($element)` should return one.

The solution is to change `hideWikipedia` to return a function that only gets called once the user clicks the element:

```
const hideWikipedia = (wikiText) => async function() { /* logic... */ };
```

In a running example (click the text to hide it after 1000ms):

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  hideWikipedia: wikiText => async function() {
    wikiText.style.animationName = "goUp";
    await sleep(1000); 
    wikiText.style.display = "none";
  }
});

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

```css
#wikipedia-text {
  background: #efefef;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes goUp {
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="wikipedia-text" data-bind="click: hideWikipedia($element)">Hello world</div>
<p> ⬆ Click to hide </p>
```